# Use dart reflectable on external lib

Tags: reflection, dart, dart-mirrors

I need to use reflectable on a third party lib but it is not working.

Consider this scenario:

Library A has the reflector declaration:

```
class Reflector extends Reflectable {
    const Reflector()
        : super(invokingCapability,
        typeRelationsCapability,
        metadataCapability,
        superclassQuantifyCapability,
        reflectedTypeCapability);
}

const Reflector reflector = const Reflector();
```

Library B has the classes that are annotated with the reflector:

```
import 'package:library_a/library_a.dart' show reflector;

@reflector
class whateverz {}
```

Now the application C needs to use reflection on whateverz class that is within library B.

My problem is that the reflectable lib can't see the whateverz class annotated. The build warns "reflector.dart: This reflector does not match anything"

And if I do "print(reflector.annotatedClasses);" it prints [] within the console.

Is this possible? To annotate the classes on a third party lib that I will end up using in an application with reflection?
If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the transformation isn't being performed on the correct main file.

The transformer is capable of looking up any declaration in your program, so if there is a library in your program which is importing library B (and hence also library A) then the transformer should certainly be able to generate a mirror for `class whateverz`, and you should find that mirror in `reflector.annotatedClasses`.

But the set of files taken into account during transformation is the transitive closure of the imports from your entry point (that is, the relevant element in the `entry_points` specified in your `pubspec.yaml`), so if you specify an entry point which is not the actual main file then the transformer may get to work with a smaller (or just different) set of libraries. For instance, if you use library A as the entry point then the transformer won't know that library B exists (assuming that library A doesn't directly or indirectly import library B), so the transformer won't discover any declarations in library B and you won't get the corresponding mirrors.

If you are working on a library that other developers will import and use, you need to tell them to include the reflectable transformer in their `pubspec.yaml` and add an element to the `entry_points` (or check that they are using a wildcard that already matches all the desired entry points).

You can check out [three_files_test.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/reflectable/blob/master/test_reflectable/test/three_files_test.dart) to see a tiny example where a reflector in one file is used to annotate classes in different files, and you can check out [meta_reflectors_test.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/reflectable/blob/master/test_reflectable/test/meta_reflectors_test.dart) to see how you can decouple reflectors, target classes, and other elements even more (e.g., by using `GlobalQuantifyCapability` to associate a certain reflector with a certain target class without editing the file that contains the target class).